# swapping two pages and have a static one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have three pages A,B,C and i want to swap right from A to B then go back, and swap left from A to C then go back ...
I'm new to jquery mobile and javascript, I've tried a lot of scripts but non of them did the job,
here is my js and html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1" >
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>page1</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>page1</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>swap</h1>
  </div>
</div> 


<div data-role="page"  id="page2">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>page2</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>page2</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>swap</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page"  id="page3">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>page3</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>page3</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>swap</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

js

```
  <script>

    $(document).on('swiperight swipeleft', function(event) {
     if (event.type == 'swiperight') {

        if(id == 'page1'){
            $.mobile.changePage("#page3");
      }
        else
      {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
      }
     }
     if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
      if(id == 'page1'){
            $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
      }
      else
      {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
      }

     }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: why are you including jqm 1.3 & 1.4 and jquery 1.10 & 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

Add in page header of #page2 and #page3

```
<a data-rel="back" href="#" data-transition="slide" direction="reverse">Back</a>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('swiperight swipeleft', "#page1", function(event) {    
  if (event.type == 'swiperight') {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
  }
  if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page3");
  }
});
```

Comment: I repeat the code for all pages and it works but i still have a problem that i need to refresh the page each time to response for the touch

Comment: you can't refresh page, in this exa. you can refresh your content using ajax call on touch and whatever event .